# comparing numeric values in a userform or cell range

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on controls for my userform. Basically, I am trying to compare the value entered in a textbox (cbofalk) to a value in a range. If it exceeds the number in that range, then it comes up with a msg box yes/no type of decision. I am driving myself crazy because I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I have scoured this forum and the solutions I have implemented all result in the same issue. I even set up a reference box (falkuclone) just to see if I was appropriately addressing the range (since I am a newb)...it pulls the number I want to look at into the reference box, but when I try to compare that number, or even that range to cbofalk, it just doesn't understand. I enter 10 into cbofalk and the number to exceed is 8.69 and it just merrily continues without the msgbox? The cell I am trying to reference ("J2"), contains a reference to a cell in a query table, but other than that I can't think of any oddity surrounding this. I have tried adding Val, doing CInt and even CLng to make sure I am comparing apples to apples, but with the same issue. It just doesn't flag the msgbox. Here is my original code surrounding the issue:

```
'code to flag a value outside of the control limits

'looks at value in falkuclone textbox and compares with cobfalk textbox and, if cbofalk is greater, triggers messagebox yes/no.
If Me.cboFalk.Value > falkuclone.Value Then
'message box yes/no logic
messageresult = MsgBox("Your falk value is out of specification. Would you like to enter anyways?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Out of Spec")

End If

If messageresult = vbNo Then

    Exit Sub
    
    Else

    'copy the data to the database
With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboFalk.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.cboTalk.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboTemp.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cbopH.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboPSI.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboDate.Value

hiddenstageone_Click
End With

'clear the userform fields
Me.cboFalk.Value = ""
Me.cboTalk.Value = ""
Me.cboTemp.Value = ""
Me.cbopH.Value = ""
Me.cboPSI.Value = ""
Me.cboFalk.SetFocus

Exit Sub

End If


End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

'make the form generate todays date when displayed
Me.cboDate.Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
'set the falkuclone textbox to equal J2 value when the userform is pulled up
falkuclone.Value = Sheets("Stage 1").Range("J2").Value


End Sub
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: We need more, how do you declare the variables? doubles? longs? when is falkuclone given a value?

Comment: Probably you are comparing strings, not numbers. An inputbox always returns a string, you should convert the value to a number using for example `CDbl`. When you compare strings, `8.69` is greater than `10` because the comparison is done char by char and the char `8` is greater than the char `1`.

Comment: looks like you may be losing the decimal values sometimes or its being detected as text sometimes so try to save them on a double variable before comparing or do a check to make sure the fields have numbers.

Comment: @RicardoA thanks for responding. falkuclone is a textbox, the value of which is declared in the userform activation trigger. I do have other declared variables related to the copying and pasting of data to the worksheet. I can provide the whole code for this userform if that is helpful, but I omitted it because I felt it would be a lot of code to sort through. Thanks again!

Comment: you have variables when copying and pasting but in the code above you are comparing textbox to textbox. and it may break when comparing decimals, also it may also be bringing in spaces/non numerical characters from the cells. Checking for a numerical value and also putting them on a double in the specific trigger above may help.

Comment: @FunThomas you are a champ! This worked great! Here is the code change I made: basically did - ElseIf CDbl(Me.cboFalk.Value) > CDbl(Me.falkuclone.Value) Then - So easy! how do I upvote or give you props on this forum? I am pretty new here.